# How to Insert New CSV Data into Existing Table (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once a month we receive .csv files from one of our software providers which contains useful data. The data contains all of the previous months data. There are quite a few columns that need to be renamed and it's faster and easier to do this is SSMS.

So, I have created a table with these headings and inserted the data. When the new month comes around, I want to remove the previous months data with;

```
TRUNCATE TABLE test_data_1;
```

I then want to load in the new months .csv file against the existing table with the existing headings, which prevents me having to rename them all again.

Is this achievable or will I just have to DROP the table and re-upload a flat file each time?

Thanks!!

Ben

Comment: To answer your question: "Yes". What is your programming question here though? You haven't given us a problem to solve. What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Have you tried bcp command to achieve it?

Comment: SSMS itself has an Import Data wizard that works with multiple sources and a Flat File Import wizard that can guess the format, types of CSVs. Both allow you to map source columns to target columns. All of these are covered in the documentation, blog posts etc. You can even store the SSIS package generated by the Import Data wizard and run it periodically with a SQL Server agent job

Comment: @Larnu My programming question is, how do I import csv data into an existing table in SMSS? The problem to solve is how to import csv data into an existing table within SMSS. Using the Flat File Import wizard seems to create new tables with the newly loaded data, meaning I have to rename all of the columns again. Sorry, I hope this makes sense!

Comment: @Conifers Hi, I haven't no! I shall investigate, unless you have any code you can give me to get me started?

Comment: The Import Flat File is specifically for **new** tables. As per the introduction screen. *"This wizard will help you import the contents of a file in a **new table** in your database."* If you want to import to an existing object, use bcp or (which i think would be better) create an SSIS Package. If you must, use the `Import Data` tool instead as a base, and then create your SSIS package from that,.